# Combine two input verticaly in one form using Bootstrap 3

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

[bootstrap http://i.stack.img](http://i.stack.img)

```html
<link href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
                   <form>
                       <div class="input-group inp">
                           <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-user fa-fw"></i></span>
                           <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Email address">
                       </div>
                       <div class="input-group inp">
                           <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-key fa-fw"></i></span>
                           <input class="form-control" type="password" placeholder="Password">
                       </div>
                   </form>
                </div>
```

ur.com/liYfx.png

Good evening . Can you help me with bootstrap? I can not  combine two inputs into  one form  and add Font Awesome icon using Twitter Botstrap , like in this picture. Thank You  very much .

Comment: share you code, so we can help you in right direction

Comment: do you have any code? if not check getbootstrap.com first and try to make something that we can work on to help you with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did something similar in my last project so here you go:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <form role="form">
      <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
        <div class="form-group">
          <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span></span>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="MinVal">
          </div>
        <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span></span>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="MinVal">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Working fiddle:

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/d7dt0vv7/1/)

Fiddle update:

[UpdateFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/d7dt0vv7/4/)

Comment: No , I have just do the same thing. I need to create inout look like in picture.THANK YOU

Comment: Edit your question, fix the image and I will try to make what you need.

Comment: Okay but you still need some help or problem is already solved?

Comment: Okay I have updated my fiddle but how I can help you when you can't even edit your question and fix the image?

Comment: Thank   YOU very very much. Your solution help me a lot.